# Splitting a pipeline in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Assume that I have a Spark pipeline like this (formatted to emphasize the important steps):

```
val foos1 = spark_session.read(foo_file).flatMap(toFooRecord)
  .map(someComplicatedProcessing)
  .map(transform1)
  .distinct().collect().toSet
```

I'm adding a similar pipeline:

```
val foos2 = spark_session.read(foo_file).flatMap(toFooRecord)
  .map(someComplicatedProcessing)
  .map(transform2)
  .distinct().collect().toSet
```

Then I do something with both results.

I'd like to avoid doing `someComplicatedProcessing` twice (not parsing the file twice is nice, too).

Is there a way to take the stream after the `.map(someComplicatedProcessing)` step and create two parallel streams feeding off it?

I know that I can store the intermediate result on disk and thus save the CPU time at the cost of more I/O. Is there a better way? What words do I web-search for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option - `cache` intermediate results:

```
val cached = spark_session.read(foo_file).flatMap(toFooRecord)
  .map(someComplicatedProcessing)
  .cache
val foos1 = cached.map(transform1)
  .distinct().collect().toSet
val foos2 = cached.map(transform2)
  .distinct().collect().toSet
```

Second option - use `RDD` and make single pass:

```
val foos = spark_session.read(foo_file)
  .flatMap(toFooRecord)
  .map(someComplicatedProcessing)
  .rdd
  .flatMap(x => Seq(("t1", transform1(x)), ("t2", transform2(x))))
  .distinct
  .collect
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))

val foos1 = foos("t1")
val foos2 = foos("t2")
```

The second option may require some type wrangling if `transform1` and `transform2` have incompatible return types.